# How to show different colour in the same data in tableau?

Tags: python-3.x, colors, data-visualization, tableau-api, visualization

In tableau, I want the colours of my fields to be shown separately, but Tableau automatically creates a custom colour for both of the fields, which i do not want. Is there any way to show the fields in different colours? TIA
Also, if it is not possible, is there any way to do this in Python?

[This is the way it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NPnn.png)

[This is the colour setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSDVm.png)

Comment: could you please uodate your image showing your marks section in order to see what's the setting for your color mark?

Comment: I think you have added two fields to colors marks card by creating hierarchy? Am I correct?

Comment: You need to describe the result you want to achieve. "colours of fields shown separately" doesn't describe an outcome or result. Which fields? How do you want colours to combine?